# jquery validation plugin, how to add multiple custom messages in custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

I added a custom method using [addmethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) which in turn calls another method to check for valid `UK telephone number`

here is my code (simplified):

**html**

```
<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Required, telephone: </label>
  <input class="required" id="field" name="field" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules:{
            field:{
                required:true;
                UKTelNumber:true
            }
        }       
    });
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("UKTelNumber", function(value,element) {

    if (!checkUKTelephone (value)) {
        alert (telNumberErrors[telNumberErrorNo]);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }       
},jQuery.validator.format(telNumberErrors[telNumberErrorNo]));
```

The function **`checkUKTelephone`** sets the value of var **`telNumberErrorNo`** according to the type of error.
All the error messages are there in an array **`telNumberErrors`**.

Now my requirement is that how to show those error messages that is being alerted now.

passing `jQuery.validator.format(telNumberErrors[telNumberErrorNo])` as message (third option) of [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) is not helping.

I also tried passing only this `telNumberErrors[telNumberErrorNo]` but its showing only one message every time i.e message contained in `telNumberErrors[0]`

plz help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I got the solution to my question so I thought to answer my own question that it may help others

just create a function and return the error which is being alerted

```
var dispError = function(){
    return telNumberErrors[telNumberErrorNo];
}
```

and then pass that function as the third argument to [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("UKTelNumber", function(value,element) {    
    if (!checkUKTelephone (value)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }       
},dispError);
```

then call the validate method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules:{
            field:{
                required:true;
                UKTelNumber:true
            }
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example:

```
$.validator.addMethod('variable', function (value, element, params) {
    if (!/[a-z]/i.test(value[0])) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    } else if (/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';.,/(){}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(value)) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    } else {
        return this.optional(element) || true;
    }
}, function(error, element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    if (!/[a-z]/i.test(value[0])) {
        return 'First character must be a letter'
    }
    if (/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';.,/(){}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(value)) {
        return 'No special characters except: _'
    }   
})
```