# jQuery Image Validation For Dynamically Cloned Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form in my HTML that will get cloned and appended dynamically when the user hits the #addOne button. The form gets validated successfully for any input errors, the only problem that I am facing right now is that it's not working correctly for images. Let's say I upload an image for the first form, it works perfect. But when I click the #addOne button and upload an image for the second form, that's when the problems arise. Prior to even uploading an image for the second form, it's already displaying the image from the previous form on to the page. Uploading an image for this form, will not update form 2. Rather, it'll change form 1's displayed image. How can I make it so that each form displays it's own uploaded image and is validated properly? Here's my **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="article_properties">

  <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
    <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

      <p style="display: inline" class="pageNumber"></p>
    </div>
    <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pages"></textarea>
    <p>Image</p>
    <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image" class="pageImg">
    <div class="imgContainer">
    </div>
    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <input type="text" name="subtitle">

    <p>Text</p>
    <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update" name="properties_submit">
    <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
  </form>


  <a style="display: none; text-align: center; margin: 50px; font-size: 25px" class="expand" href="#">

  </a>
</div>
<!--End of article properties div-->
<div id="addOne">
  <p>+Add page</p>
</div>

<div class="nextBtn" style="display: none">
  <p>Finalize my article</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var numPagesTemp = 4;
$('.pageNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
$('.inputNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
//Invoke functions for first form
add_validation_for_forms();
add_image_construction();

//Form validation
function add_validation_for_forms() {
  $(".article_properties_form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
      errorElement: 'div',

      rules: {
        image: {
          required: true,
          extension: "jpg|jpeg|png",
          minImageSize: {
            width: 600,
            height: 400
          }
        },

        subtitle: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 25
        },
        text: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 35,
          maxlength: 275
        }
      },

      messages: {
        image: {
          required: "This page needs an image",
          extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
        },

        subtitle: {
          required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
          minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
          maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
        },
        text: {
          required: "Please enter text for this page",
          minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
          maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
        },
      },
    });
  });
}
//Adding a form
$('#addOne').click(function() {

  numPagesTemp--;

  var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
  articlePropsTemplate.show();
  $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);

  var articlePropsExpand = $('.expand:last').clone();
  articlePropsExpand.text("Expand " + numPagesTemp);
  articlePropsExpand.hide();

  $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsExpand);

  $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
  $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
  articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
  add_validation_for_forms();

  add_image_construction();
  articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();

  if (numPagesTemp == 1) {
    $('#addOne').hide();
    $(".nextBtn").show();
  }

});

//Adding Method
$.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
  var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
  return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height);
}, function(minSize, element) {
  return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
});

//Image Uploading
var $properties_btn = $('properties_btn'),
  $imgContainer = $('.imgContainer'),
  $pageImg = $('.pageImg');

function add_image_construction() {

  $('.pageImg').change(function() {
    $pageImg.removeData('imageSize');
    $imgContainer.hide().empty();

    var file = this.files[0];

    if (file.type.match(/image\/.*/)) {
      $properties_btn.attr('disabled', true);

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function() {
        var $img = $('<img />').attr({
          src: reader.result
        });

        $img.on('load', function() {
          $imgContainer.append($img).show();

          $pageImg.data('imageSize', {
            width: $img.width(),
            height: $img.height()
          });

          $img.css({
            width: '400px',
            height: '200px'
          });

          $properties_btn.attr('disabled', false);

          validator.element($pageImg);
        });
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      validator.element($pageImg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Note, cloned `form` would create duplicate `id` `#properties_btn` in `document`

Comment: @guest2713148 hmm the form works perfect without the image dimension validation, but with it it's messing up

Comment: Should image be removed from cloned `form`?

Comment: @guest271314  The image in the cloned forms should reset, and the user should upload a new image. There will be 4 forms, and a total of 4 different images the user has uploaded, if that makes sense. Each form is technically a unique form that will contain different values.

Comment: Note also, `validator` does not defined at jsfiddle. You have defined variables which are being referenced at cloned `form` pointing to original `form`

Comment: @guest271314 yes, but I don't understand how I can fix this so it'll work, where should I put the variables?

Comment: Is [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/2/) doing what you want?

Comment: @JohnS Yes! This works perfectly!

Comment: Actually, there is one bug in it. You were not defining the `validator` variable. Fixed in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/3/).

Comment: @JohnS I have another form which contains 3 image upload inputs. Each upload input has different validation dimension requirements. Would I need to copy the Javascript, that you provided to me, multiple times?

Comment: Each input should have a different name. When you call `.validate()` on the form and set the rules for each input, use different dimensions for the `minImageSize` method.

Comment: @JohnS So I should copy the minImageSize method and change the name of it for the different dimensions?

Comment: No need to copy the method and change the name. You can use the same method for all three inputs. The three inputs should have different names, like `name="image1"`, `name="image2"`, `name="image3"`.

Comment: @JohnS Oh I see, what about the Javascript? For example, I have an if/else statement where if the image is less than 600px wide it should not display, but what if for image2 I want it to display if it's less than 600px wide and more than 300px wide?

Comment: You would have to make those minimums depend on the specific file input for which the change-event fired. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/4/) that shows how you could use `data-*` attributes to do something like that.

Comment: @JohnS Hmm, for some reason the error messages aren't displaying. I tried inserting the full message blocks, but they're still not displaying for some reason in that jsfiddle

Comment: I was focused on the setting of the image size after it was loaded, not the error messages. I forgot to change the `name` values for the inputs. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/6/).

Comment: @JohnS My .article_properties_form is the form with 2 input fields and one image field. I have another form which is .social_properties_form with 3 image field and input fields. Both forms are on the same page because the page does not refresh, so when the user gets done with one, the other will show after completion. Shouldn't I copy the Javascript and change the $form variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice when cloning is this:

> Never clone elements that have been instrumented.

By instrumented, I mean they have JavaScript behavior set up on them, like event handling.

Instead do the following:

(1) Clone the elements before they have been instrumented and keep the clone in a variable.

```
var $CLONED_FORM = $('.article_properties_form:first').clone();
```

(2) Provide a function that will instrument the set of elements that are to be cloned.

```
function initializeForm($form, pageNum) {
  // Set up form validation here.
  // Also attach the change-event handler for the file input here.
}
```

(3) Call the function for the sets that are already on the page.

```
$('.article_properties_form').each(function() {
  initializeForm($(this), numPagesTemp--);
});
```

(4) When you want to add another set of the elements, ***clone the clone*** and add it, and call the function on it.

```
$('#addOne').click(function() {
  var $newForm = $CLONED_FORM.clone().appendTo('.article_properties').show();

  initializeForm($newForm, numPagesTemp--);

  if (numPagesTemp == 0) {
    $('#addOne').hide();
    $(".nextBtn").show();
  }
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsnc30o/3/)

---

You also need to store the validator object in a variable named `validator`.

```
var validator = $form.validate({
```

---

Also, you should avoid duplicate `id` values when cloning. You have an `id` on the form submit button, but it does not appear to be needed, so perhaps you can just remove that.

Comment: Everything's working as it should now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use my code

Edit, Updated

Substituted `class="properties_btn"` for `id="properties_btn"` to prevent duplicate `id` being appended to `document`; defined `validator` at `change` event.

```js
$(function() {
  var numPagesTemp = 4;
  $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
  $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
  //Invoke functions for first form
  add_validation_for_forms();
  add_image_construction();

  //Form validation
  function add_validation_for_forms() {
      $(".article_properties_form").each(function() {
        $(this).validate({
          errorElement: 'div',

          rules: {
            image: {
              required: true,
              extension: "jpg|jpeg|png",
              minImageSize: {
                width: 600,
                height: 400
              }
            },

            subtitle: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 25
            },
            text: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 35,
              maxlength: 275
            }
          },

          messages: {
            image: {
              required: "This page needs an image",
              extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
            },

            subtitle: {
              required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
              minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
              maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
            },
            text: {
              required: "Please enter text for this page",
              minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
              maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
            },
          },
        });
      });
    }
    //Adding a form
  $('#addOne').click(function() {

    numPagesTemp--;

    var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last')
      .clone();
    articlePropsTemplate.find("img").remove();
    $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);

    var articlePropsExpand = $('.expand:last').clone();
    articlePropsExpand.text("Expand " + numPagesTemp);
    articlePropsExpand.hide();


    $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsExpand);

    $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
    $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPagesTemp);
    $("form:last")[0].reset();
    add_validation_for_forms();

    // add_image_construction();
    articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();

    if (numPagesTemp == 1) {
      $('#addOne').hide();
      $(".nextBtn").show();
    }
    

  });

  //Adding Method
  $.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
    var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
    return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height);
  }, function(minSize, element) {
    return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
  });

  //Image Uploading
  //  var $properties_btn = $('.properties_btn'),
  //  $imgContainer = $('.imgContainer'),
  //  $pageImg = $('.pageImg');

  function add_image_construction() {

    $(document).on("change", ".pageImg", function(e) {
      var form = $(this).closest("form");
      var validator = form.validate();
      $(this).removeData('imageSize');
      form.find('.imgContainer').hide().empty();

      var file = this.files[0];

      if (file.type.match(/image\/.*/)) {
        form.find('.properties_btn').attr('disabled', true);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {
          var $img = $('<img />').attr({
            src: reader.result
          });

          $img.on('load', function() {
            form.find('.imgContainer').append($img).show();

            $(e.target).data('imageSize', {
              width: $img.width(),
              height: $img.height()
            });

            $img.css({
              width: '400px',
              height: '200px'
            });

            form.find('.properties_btn').attr('disabled', false);

            validator.element(e.target);
          });
        }

        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        validator.element(e.target);
      }
      
    });
  }
  
})
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_properties">

  <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
    <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

      <p style="display: inline" class="pageNumber"></p>
    </div>
    <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pages"></textarea>
    <p>Image</p>
    <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image" class="pageImg">
    <div class="imgContainer">
    </div>
    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <input type="text" name="subtitle">

    <p>Text</p>
    <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input class="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update" name="properties_submit">
    <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
  </form>


  <a style="display: none; text-align: center; margin: 50px; font-size: 25px" class="expand" href="#">

  </a>
</div>
<!--End of article properties div-->
<div id="addOne">
  <p>+Add page</p>
</div>

<div class="nextBtn" style="display: none">
  <p>Finalize my article</p>
</div>
```

---

This is a simplified version of what you are trying to achieve, without validating uploaded file

```js
// maximum number of `form` elements which `document` should contain
var n = 4;
// display `form` index
function handleLabel() {
  $("label").html(function(index, html) {
    return "form #" + index 
  })
}

handleLabel();

function processFile() {
  // preview uploaded image
  $("<img>", {src: URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])})
  .insertAfter(this.nextElementSibling).after("<br>");
  
}
// handle file upload; delegate event to `document`
$(document).on("change", ":file", processFile);
// append cloned `form` to page
$("button").on("click", function() {
  // if less than `n` forms
  if ($("form").length < 4) {
  // copy last `form` `.outerHTML` instead of using `.clone()`
  $($("form:last")[0].outerHTML)
    // remove `img` from `html`
    .find("img").remove().end()
    .insertAfter("form:last");
    // update `form` `label` elements
    handleLabel();
  } else {
    // detach `click` event from `button`
    // when four `form` elements exist in `document`
    $(this).off("click")
  }
});
// handle `form` submit event
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
  // check `img` `width`, `height`
  if (img.naturalWidth < 600 
    || img.naturalHeight < 400) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.reset();
      alert("invalid img width or height")
    }
})
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label></label><br>
    <input name="file" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" required />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button>
  add form
</button>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hLjvffpv/5/

Comment: How can I implement this with what I have?

Comment: Have not tried `jquery-validate`, though you can include `required` attribute at `<input type="file" required />` element, and adjust `accept` attribute to `accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"` to require upload of `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, or `.png` file upload before `form` submission.

Comment: @user2896120 See https://jsfiddle.net/hLjvffpv/5/. Added check for `img` `width` and `height` at `form` `submit` event `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
  if (img.naturalWidth < 600 
    || img.naturalHeight < 400) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.reset();
      alert("invalid img width or height")
    }
})`

Comment: I need to use my code because each form is its own form. For example, when I click the submit button I want the form to stay on the page.

Comment: Works well, but for some reason when I get past form 1, the images are printed more than once

Comment: @user2896120 See updated post. `add_image_construction()` was being called at each click at `#addOne` element, attaching a second `change` event to `document`. Commented `add_image_construction()` at `#addOne` click handler.